# R vs. Python Decision Tree

Tags: machine-learning, python, r, decision-trees

From my experiences the R Decision tree returns more accurate results than the python decision tree. Can anymore confirm this assumption and maybe knows the reason?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Decision trees involve a lot of hyperparameters -

- min / max samples in each leaf/leaves
- size
- depth of tree
- criteria for splitting (gini/entropy) etc

Now different packages may have different default settings. Even within `R` or `python` if you use multiple packages and compare results, chances are they will be different.

There is nothing which suggests `R` is *"better"*

If you want to get the same results, you need to make sure the implicit defaults are similar. For instance, try running the following:

```
fit <- rpart(y_train ~ ., data = x_train,method="class",
             parms = list(split = "gini"), 
             control = rpart.control(minsplit = 2, minbucket = 1, xval=0, maxdepth = 30))

(predicted5= predict(fit,x_test))
    setosa versicolor virginica
149      0  0.3333333 0.6666667
```

Here, the parameters `minsplit = 2, minbucket = 1, xval=0` and `maxdepth = 30` are chosen so as to be identical to the `sklearn`-options, see [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html). `maxdepth = 30` is the largest value `rpart` will let you have;

`sklearn` on the other hand has no bound here. If you want `probabilities` to be identical, you probably want to play around with the `cp` parameter as well.

Similarly, with

```
model = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion='gini', 
                                    min_samples_split=20, 
                                    min_samples_leaf=round(20.0/3.0), max_depth=30)
model.fit(iris.data, iris.target)
```

I get

```
print model.predict([iris.data[49]])
print model.predict([iris.data[99]])
print model.predict([iris.data[100]])
print model.predict([iris.data[149]])
print model.predict([[6.3,2.8,6,1.3]])

[0]
[1]
[2]
[2]
[1]
```

which looks similar to your initial `R` output.

All in all, I believe the defaults in `R` are better suited for the dataset that you are working on, hence the *"better"* results. But rest assured, they are similar given the parameters are explicit and equal.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I actually hate this about R.  Sometimes the default values do a lot of heavy lifting.  And, they’re often reasonable, so you never think to screw with them.

Comment: It looks like it is not easy to replicate `cp` in python: "The lambda is determined through cross-validation and not reported in R." source:
https://www.learnbymarketing.com/tutorials/rpart-decision-trees-in-r/#:~:text=The%20complexity%20parameter%20(cp)%20in,misclassification%20at%20every%20terminal%20node.

Answer (score 5):

The main difference is that the R/rpart implementation has post pruning, while scikit learn doesn't. I may lead to a lot of overfitting in case of scikit learn.

Comment: Looks like post-pruning was added in v0.22, it's the ccp_alpha parameter.

Answer (score 5):

It also looks like rpart directly handles categorical variables, but [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#preprocessing-categorical-features) doesn't.

> **Why do categorical variables need preprocessing in scikit-learn,
>   compared to other tools?**
>   Most of scikit-learn assumes data is in NumPy
>   arrays or SciPy sparse matrices of a single numeric dtype. These do
>   not explicitly represent categorical variables at present. Thus,
>   unlike R’s data.frames or pandas.DataFrame, we require explicit
>   conversion of categorical features to numeric values, as discussed in
>   Encoding categorical features. See also Column Transformer with Mixed
>   Types for an example of working with heterogeneous (e.g. categorical
>   and numeric) data.